# How do I use the --work-tree option with git? I keep getting an error

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-commit

I have a normal repo where there is a working tree and a .git folder in the same directory as the working tree.

I'm trying to run a git command from outside this location with the command

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/repo pull /some/other/repo master
```

but I keep getting the error `fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your current working directory?  What version of Git are you using?

Comment: It's like this: all the files (the work tree) are inside some folder like `/some/repo` and inside this folder is also a .git folder `/some/repo/.git`. I would normally run git commands from inside `/some/repo`. I have version `1.7.2.3`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in earlier versions of Git.  This problem should go away once you upgrade to 1.7.7.2 or later.

From [the commit that fixed the bug](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=035b5bf6431dbf8f3cde2f44b0d7ef893b95b605):

```
You can't currently run git-pull or git-rebase from outside
of the work tree, even with GIT_WORK_TREE set, due to an
overeager require_work_tree function. Commit e2eb527
documents this problem and provides the infrastructure for a
fix, but left it to later commits to audit and update
individual scripts.
```

See also [commit e2eb527](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=e2eb527345d48881dac0d88e6bdfc0a267a2eb62).